# Embedded form in Symfony 1.4 and validator compare

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I created embedded forms with this tutorial: http://prendreuncafe.com/blog/post/2009/11/29/Embedding-Relations-in-Forms-with-Symfony-1.3-and-Doctrine

but i have one problem. How can i compare two or more values in this example? I would like compare **name** in table **Bookmark**, for example only one **name** can be with numbers. I can make this, but i dont know where i must set Validator for this. In BookmarkForm.class.php i have only one value, i can't get all values in Form. Where in this example i have all values and i can use own Validator form Symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite if this is what you're asking for, but a [postValidator](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/02-Form-Validation#chapter_02_global_validators) will allow you to do validation that requires access to multiple fields.

Here's an example of how to create a [custom postValidator](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms#chapter_06_sub_creating_a_custom_validator).

Comment: ok, but what i must fill in instead of **password** and **password_again**? how can i get all values in my form and next use compare?

Comment: @ChrisFeyst I've added another example with custom post-validator.